# Discord.py rewrite and sending images - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I'm an intermediate python user and a decently experienced Selenium user, and wanted to combine those skills with my small knowledge of the new discord.py rewrite. The code I have created runs selenium headless - it navigates to a website, fills out the form, and then takes a screenshot. The problem that I have encountered is with the channel.send file feature of discord.py. Here is my code -

```
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(guildcode)
    valid_users = ["discord#tag"]
    if str(message.author) in valid_users:
        if message.content.find("!gen") != -1:
            await message.channel.send("Generating coupon now...")
            driver.get('example.com')
            elem = driver.find_element_by_name("CN1")
            elem.click()
            elem.clear()
            surveyCode = '36901999912012386'
            elem.send_keys(surveyCode)
            clicksDone = 0
            while int(clicksDone) < 25:
                elem = driver.find_element_by_id('NextButton')
                elem.click()
                clicksDone = clicksDone + int('1')
            if clicksDone == 25:
                driver.get_screenshot_as_file('capture.png')
                await message.channel.send('Generated!')
                await channel.send(file=discord.File('capture.png'))
```

The bot correctly fills out the survey, outputs that it has generated the coupon, but fails to send out the newly taken screenshot - capture.png. Here are the errors I have encountered -

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\telldunkin\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/telldunkin/discorddonut.py", line 37, in on_message
    await channel.send(file=discord.File('capture.png'))
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
```

When I get rid of the send file code, no errors arise. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The error message complains about a line of code that is not in the code that you show.

Comment: The main error, which i believe stems from the channel.send, is provided. The first error isn't on an existing line of code

Comment: Now that that's fixed, it looks like you just have a typo. It should be `message.channel.send` rather than `channel.send`, just like on the previous line that worked.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet you give I don't see the `channel` definition, I guess it's a list defined before.  Your problem is you're doing `channel.send`, not `message.channel.send` I think.

EDIT: I missread, python say there is an error on line `channel.send(message, image)`, but this line is not in your code snippet.

Here python says that `channel` is not defined, and it's true, there is no `channel = ...` in your code. The method `send` must be used on a valid `discord.Channel` object, and here you can get channel of message with `message.channel`. To send file you have to use `message.channel.send`, as regular message.